# Web api - Http 302 - SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, webapi

Good afthernoon

I have a project in sharepoint framework and a Web API project with Azure AD authentication.

In the API I have a controller with Autorize Attribute.

If the WEB API runs in localhost, when spfx call Web API Method using AadClient the   server response is **Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=.....' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44374/api/TestController') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**.

If the SPFX calls the same WEB API, but runs on Azure it works, but the local does not work.

I appreciate a lot if someone can help me